# How many times will the "SELECT" inside "IN" execute?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle12c

I have less exposure to the performance aspect of Oracle. I want to know how exactly Oracle will handle this situation:

My procedure receives a comma-separated string, which I have to split based on comma and filter.

I know this works:

```
SELECT * 
FROM some_table 
WHERE some_attribute IN (SELECT 
REGEXP_SUBSTR(comma_separated_string,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) 
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(comma_separated_string, 
'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL);
```

Since, "REG_EX" is CPU intensive, I thought of replacing the above by:

```
SELECT * 
FROM some_table 
WHERE INSTR(','|| comma_separated_string||',', ','|| some_attribute||',') > 
0;`
```

OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM some_table 
WHERE ','||comma_separated_string||',' like '%,'|| some_attribute ||',%';`
```

So, picking either one depends on how the `select` executes or, to be precise, how many times the clause after `where` executes.

Comment: I'm adding this in a comment, because i'm not 100% on this, just speaking from my experiences. While regex might seem cpu intensive on the outside, it is much more efficient than using a `like` statement. Using `like` statements will ultimately reduce performance due to how oracle produces the queries on the backend. When using an `in` statement, it doesn't exactly 'double' the amount of processing time, but it is performing an extra query against the select statement. The best advice I can give is to run those queries and time them. Personally I'd go with regex.

Comment: What's the point of the `connect by` ?

Comment: It all depends on volume and distribution of data in your table and maybe several other factors.Try running [EXPLAIN PLAN](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/EXPLAIN-PLAN.html#GUID-FD540872-4ED3-4936-96A2-362539931BA0)  for both the queries and compare the performance.

Comment: @Dortimer I executed `EXPLAIN PLAN` for these queries. `REGEXP` is way more expensive than the other two options. Also, this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#i16971) suggests that where will be executed for all rows. I analysed the costs, `LIKE` and `INSTR` are almost similar in cost. So, I have decided to go with `INSTR`

Comment: @WW. It is used to connect the multiple outputs so that the result of the query seems to return rows of a single `SELECT`

Comment: @KaushikNayak Yes, the `EXPLAIN PLAN` was of great help. It required some attention to know what it is trying to say, but of great help. The link in other comments helped too.